# How to update gui using class in python

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, label

I'm learning python and would like to have a GUI that will change the label from one message to another message when I press a button. Without using class, I can write this code and it is working fine. This working code is shown below

```
from tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

def calculate():
    my_label.configure(text='Step 1...')
    root.update()
    time.sleep(1)
    my_label.configure(text='Step 2...')


my_button = Button(root,text='calculate',command=calculate)
my_button.pack()

my_label = Label(root,text='My label')
my_label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

However, when I want to make it as class, I don't know how to change the line root.update().
I think it should be something like master.update() but that also give error. Without this line, I will see only the second message (Step 2...) and not be able to see the first message (Step 1...). Can someone help me with this please. Here is the code that I make it as class

```
from tkinter import *
import time

class Myclass:

    def __init__(self,master):
    
        self.my_button = Button(master,text='Calculate',command=self.calculate)
        self.my_button.pack()
    
        self.my_label = Label(master,text='My label')
        self.my_label.pack()
    
    def calculate(self):
        self.my_label.configure(text='Step 1...')
        time.sleep(1)

        # My problem is with this line. Don't know how to deal with it
        root.update()

        self.my_label.configure(text='Step 2...')

root = Tk()
b = Myclass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You should know that `update()` is a universal method. Every widget has this method. You can even use `self.my_label.update()`. What you should be doing is, following answer from helloworld14751

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `root.after(1000)`:

```
from tkinter import *
import time


class Myclass:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.my_button = Button(master, text='Calculate', command=self.calculate)
        self.my_button.pack()

        self.my_label = Label(master, text='My label')
        self.my_label.pack()

    def calculate(self):
        self.my_label.configure(text='Step 1...')
        # time.sleep(1)

        # My problem is with this line. Don't know how to deal with it
        # root.update()

        ## New code ##
        root.after(1000, self.config)

    def config(self):
        self.my_label.configure(text='Step 2...')


root = Tk()
b = Myclass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. This method is working. However, my real code will be much longer than this and I will have to update the label many times. I don't want to stop the function and start the new fuction every time I update the label. Is there a method to update the GUI within the 'calculate' function?

Comment: @SiriwatSoontaranon The function wont stop. `after()` is a non blocking code. Put a `print('Blocker')` after `after()` and you will notice.